# Table striped with Bootstrap 3 when I hide some tr elements dinamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is a reasonable solution to make a  table-striped  stay in it's pattern (e.g. gray-white-gray-white) even when I hide some `<tr>` elements dynamically?

Comment: `Datatable` table or normal table?

Comment: I'm talking about `html table` with Bootstrap 3 `table-striped` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `.table-striped` class from `table` and add again.

If you are using Jquery, use this code:

```
$("#tblCustomer").removeClass("table-striped");
$("#tblCustomer").addClass("table-striped");
```